# How many rings does OpenBSD use?

Tags: security, openbsd, x86

Usually a Windows/Linux operating system uses afaik [max 2 rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28computer_security%29)

But how many rings does OpenBSD use?

Comment: That was a CPU concept, and OS is a wrapper function, am I wrong?

Comment: afaik for example: OpenVMS used 4 rings. and imho the more rings are used the more secure the OS could be, -> KISS principle.

Comment: STOP used to have 3 rings, but I think the newest version was reduced to 2 for the sake of speed :(

Comment: More rings doesn't particularly translate to more security. It's not how many rings you have, it's how you use them.

Comment: One Ring for the Elvis editor and Plone, //
One for user processes doomed to die, //
Three for the kernel in its dark zone //
In OpenBSD where the Blowfish lie. [No, I don't know whether OpenBSD actually uses more than two rings.]

Answer (score 3):

All BSD systems have 2 protection rings, and yes, it depends on the CPU architecture. By now, OpenBSD uses ring0 for kernel and ring3 for userland.
That's it.